# Is there a way for my Android app to create an environment similar to how work profiles in Android for Work work?

Tags: android

I want my app to be able to create an environment where it can freely install and delete apps from this environment. The main purpose for this is so my app can install and update apk files for supporting apps without having to inform the user every time this happens. Is creating this environment possible?

Comment: Like an OS in Virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, that's very similar to what I want. In a sense, I want my app to be able to create a personal space to run apps on the user's phone, and then clear that space when my app is done.